# Why is Late Binding not working as i expected?

Tags: java, inheritance, late-binding

The following code outputs 7:

```java
public class GuessTheAnswer {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        A obj = new H();
        int jj;
        jj = obj.m(new E());
        System.out.println(jj);
    }
}
class A {
    public int m(C c) { return 8; }
}
class B extends A {
    public int m(C c) { return 7; }
    public int m(D c) { return 6; }
    public int m(E c) { return 5; }
}

class C {}
class D extends C {}
class E extends D {}
interface I {
    public int m(I obj);
}
class H extends B implements I{
    public int m(I c) { return 12; }
    public int m(D c) { return 13; }
    public int m(E c) { return 14; }
}
```

I would have expected `obj.m(new E())` to refer to the method m(E c) defined in class H, but for some reason i don't understand the method in class B is called instead.

Comment: Try reducing this way too convoluted code to a more simple example. There's too much going on here to easily reason about. Using understandable names instead of single-letter names might help as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's what happens:

`obj` is of declared type `A`, so only methods that are defined inside `A` are taken into account. And the only method that `A` has is `int m(C c)`. Only this method and its overridden versions are going to be candidates for the binding.
The methods declared in `H` are overloaded versions of this method, so they are not accessible when you make a method call inside main.

Comment: This makes sense, so I'm guessing in general I should look for the method in the declared type and then find the closest overridden method (if present) to `H`. Am i correct?

Comment: Yeah, I think it's a good way to think about it.